# how to read Currencies Exchange Rates right?

Tags: php, laravel, currency, finance, currency-exchange-rates

**Does anyone know a way to read the currency exchange rates right in laravel?**

We develop web exchange currency so I have a problem when I put right rates but get a different results.

**Example**: Exchange between  USD TO EGP : 1 USD = 15.70 EGP  So i need to Put the Currency USD TO get 15.70 EGP but if i put this will get Rates - 1 USD = 4 EGP not 15.70

**Follow the pictures to understand**

1-

[image]

2-

[image]

3-

[image]

4-

[image]

**So my question is:**

Does anybody know a way to solve these rates?

**Home Blade**

```
<form class="exchange-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('user.exchange') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="send">@lang('You Send')</label>
                            <input type="text" name="send_amount" id="send_val" placeholder="@lang('Send')" required
                                onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/^\.|[^\d\.]/g, '')">
                            <select class="select-bar" name="send" id="send">
                                <option value="">@lang('Select Currency')</option>
                                @foreach ($currencys_sell as $currency)
                                    <option value="{{ $currency->id }}"
                                        data-min_max="{{ filterCollection($currency, 'rate', 'sell_at', 'buy_at', 'fixed_charge', 'percent_charge', 'reserve', 'min_exchange', 'max_exchange', 'cur_sym', 'payment_type_sell') }}">
                                        {{ $currency->name }} {{$currency->cur_sym}}
                                    </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            <div class="exchange-limit exchange-buy d-none">
                                <div class="item">
                                    <span class="subtitle">@lang('Min')</span>
                                    <span class="amount min-amount"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <span class="subtitle">@lang('Max')</span>
                                    <span class="amount max-amount"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group receiveData">
                            <label for="receive">@lang('You Get')</label>

                            <input type="text" name="receive_amount" id="receive_val" min="0" placeholder="@lang('Receive')"
                                readonly>
                            <select class="select-bar" name="receive" id="receive">
                                <option value="" class="wrap">@lang('Select Currency')</option>
                                @foreach ($currencys_buy as $currency)
                                    <option value="{{ $currency->id }}"
                                        data-min_max="{{ filterCollection($currency, 'cur_sym', 'rate', 'sell_at', 'buy_at', 'fixed_charge', 'percent_charge', 'reserve', 'min_exchange', 'max_exchange', 'payment_type_sell') }}">
                                        {{ $currency->name }} {{$currency->cur_sym}}
                                    </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            <div class="exchange-limit reserve-section d-none">
                                <div class="item reserve">
                                    <span class="subtitle">@lang('Reserve')</span>
                                    <span class="amount"></span>
                                </div>

                                    <div class="item reserve">
                                    <span class="subtitle">@lang('Rate')</span>
                                    <span class="amount conversion"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**Home Controller**

```
public function exchange(Request $request)
{
    session()->forget('Track');

    $receive = Currency::find($request->receive);
    $send = Currency::find($request->send);

   

    if ($receive == null) {
        $notify[] = ['error', 'Select any method that we send u the money'];
        return back()->withNotify($notify);
    }

    if ($send == null) {
        $notify[] = ['error', 'Select any method that we get money'];
        return back()->withNotify($notify);
    }

    $field = json_decode($receive->user_input);

    $validate_array = [
        'send' => 'required|numeric',
        'send_amount' => 'required|numeric|gt:0',
        'receive' => 'required|numeric',
        'receive_amount' => 'required|numeric|gt:0',

    ];
    foreach ($field as $value) {
        if (strtolower($value->type) === 'email') {
            $validate_array[$value->field_name] = "sometimes|{$value->validation}|email";
            continue;
        }

        $validate_array[$value->field_name] = "sometimes|{$value->validation}";
    }

    $this->validate($request, $validate_array);


    // new Calculation for covert amount 

    $percentCharge = ($request->send_amount * $send->percent_charge) / 100;

    $totalCharge = $percentCharge + $send->fixed_charge;

    $totalSendAmount = $request->send_amount - $totalCharge;

    $sendAmountConvertInBaseCurrency =  $totalSendAmount * $send->buy_at;

    $userReceiveAmount = $sendAmountConvertInBaseCurrency / $receive->sell_at;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what is the problem or how it's related to PHP. Can you please share a code example of what you've tried?

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/0zz466xz  @OfirBaruch    please follow picture to understand the rates not correct when i put 15.70 EGP not get me same Number but to get this number needed to put 4.5

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/g68dm5w7  Controller php  @OfirBaruch

Answer (score 0):

Open the code and choose the first option from option and add to it as follows

@lang('Select Currency')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).